# Values are getting added into the list as multiple list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list with multiple dictionaries (key, value) pairs. For example, if there is a student and he studies in different time slots, then I have to merge the different time schedules into one list. I am fetching data from the database one by.

The fetched values look like this:

```
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':9,'end':10}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':11,'end':12}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':13,'end':15}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':16,'end':19}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':20,'end':21}}
```

What I need is

```
{
    'name':'a',
    'study_time':[
        {'start':9,'end':10},
        {'start':11,'end':12},
        {'start':13,'end':15},
        {'start':16,'start':19},
    ],
}
```

What I get is

```
{
    'name':'a',
    'study_time': [
        [
            [
                {'start':9,'end':10},
                {'start':11,'end':12},
            ],
            {'start':13,'end':15},
            {'start':16,'start':19},
        ],
        {'start':20,'end':21},
    ],
}
```

What I tried is

```py
parsed_user_details=[]
if len(parsed_user_details) == 0:
    parsed_user_details.append(parsed_user_detail)
    print("I am inside if", parsed_user_details,file=sys.stderr)
else:
    parsed_user_details[0]['time'] = [
        parsed_user_details[0]['time'],
        parsed_user_detail['time'],
    ]
    print("I am inside else", parsed_user_details)
```

Overall What I have tried is if the time list is 0 just append the values into the list else add the values into the list.
MY parsed user detail is
parsed_user_detail = {'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':9,'end':10}}
whenever I loop it I get the below parsed_user_detail one by one.

```
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':9,'end':10}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':11,'end':12}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':13,'end':15}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':16,'end':19}}
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':20,'end':21}}
```

Comment: What are the variables `user_details` and `parsed_user_details`? Could you add their definition?

Comment: Also: you have many similarly-named variables (`parsed_user_details`, `parsed_userr_detail` and `parsed_user_detail`); are those typos or are those really all separate variables?

Comment: what if there are different names ?

Comment: Yes I have edited the questions.parsed_user_detail and parsed_user_details are different variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close :

```
list_dict = [{'name':'a',"study_time":{'start':9,'end':10}},
{'name':'a',"study_time":{'start':11,'end':12}},
{'name':'a',"study_time":{'start':13,'end':15}},
{'name':'a',"study_time":{'start':16,'end':19}}]

name = list_dict[0]["name"]

parsed_user_details = []

for i in list_dict : 
  if len(parsed_user_details) == 0:
    parsed_user_details.append(i)
    parsed_user_details[0]["study_time"] = [parsed_user_details[0]["study_time"]]
  else : 
    parsed_user_details[0]['study_time'].append(i['study_time'])



print(parsed_user_details)
```

you needed to add this, make the first study_time an array then append to it :

```
parsed_user_details[0]["study_time"] = [parsed_user_details[0]["study_time"]]
```

output :

```
{'name': 'a',
  'study_time': [{'end': 10, 'start': 9},
   {'end': 12, 'start': 11},
   {'end': 15, 'start': 13},
   {'end': 19, 'start': 16}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [[Python 3.Docs]: itertools.**groupby**(*iterable, key=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). I also added other users records to increase complexity:

> ```py
> >>> import itertools
> >>> import pprint
> >>>
> >>> mixed_records = [
> ...     {"name": "a", "study_time": {"start": 9,"end": 10}},
> ...     {"name": "b", "study_time": {"start": 8,"end": 9}},  # Added
> ...     {"name": "a", "study_time": {"start": 11,"end": 12}},
> ...     {"name": "a", "study_time": {"start": 13,"end": 15}},
> ...     {"name": "a", "study_time": {"start": 16,"end": 19}},
> ...     {"name": "a", "study_time": {"start": 20,"end": 21}},
> ...     {"name": "b", "study_time": {"start": 12,"end": 14}},  # Added
> ... ]
> >>>
> >>> sorted_records = sorted(mixed_records, key=lambda x: x["name"])  # Sort records by their name
> >>>
> >>> for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_records, key=lambda x: x["name"]):  #  Group the sorted records by their names
> ...     users_data.append({"name": k, "study_time": [item["study_time"] for item in g]})  # Reconstruct the user dictionary
> ...
> >>> pprint.pprint(users_data)
> [{'name': 'a',
>   'study_time': [{'end': 10, 'start': 9},
>                  {'end': 12, 'start': 11},
>                  {'end': 15, 'start': 13},
>                  {'end': 19, 'start': 16},
>                  {'end': 21, 'start': 20}]},
>  {'name': 'b',
>   'study_time': [{'end': 9, 'start': 8}, {'end': 14, 'start': 12}]}]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So I have a sort of solution that is a bit roundabout but gets your result.
I assume that you may actually have different names and want an object for each?

```
from collections import defaultdict
l1 = [{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':9,'end':10}},
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':11,'end':12}},
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':13,'end':15}},
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':16,'end':19}},
{'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':20,'end':21}},]

dict_holder = defaultdict(list)
for d in l1:
    dict_holder[d['name']].append(d['study_time'])

new_dicts = []
for name, study_list in dict_holder.items():
    new_dicts.append({'name': name, 'study_time': study_list})

new_dicts
[{
     'name': 'a', 
     'study_time': [
         {'start': 9, 'end': 10}, 
         {'start': 11, 'end': 12}, 
         {'start': 13, 'end': 15}, 
         {'start': 16, 'end': 19}, 
         {'start': 20, 'end': 21}]
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a built-in only solution, try this:

```py
data = [
    {'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':9,'end':10}},
    {'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':11,'end':12}},
    {'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':13,'end':15}},
    {'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':16,'end':19}},
    {'name':'a', 'study_time':{'start':20,'end':21}}
]

result = []
for entry in data:
    item = next(
        (x for x in result if x.get('name') == entry.get('name')),
        None
    )
    if not item:
        item = {
            'name': entry.get('name'),
            'study_time': []
        }
        result.append(item)
    item['study_time'].append(entry.get('study_time'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the expected result is a list of multiple dictionaries theb you can do this.

```py
from itertools import groupby

def get_studetails(student):
    res = {}
    for i in student:
        if not res.get('name'):
            res['name'] = i.get('name')
        if not res.get('study_time') or res.get('study_time') == []:
            res['study_time'] = []
            res['study_time'].append(i.get('study_time'))
        else:
            temp_study = res.get('study_time') 
            temp_study.append(i.get('study_time'))
            res['study_time'] = temp_study
    return res

total_list = []

studentdetailsl = [{'name':'a','study_time':{'start':9,'end':10}},{'name':'a','study_time':{'start':11,'end':12}},{'name':'a','study_time':{'start':13,'end':15}},{'name':'a','study_time':{'start':16,'end':19}},{'name':'a','study_time':{'start':20,'end':21}}, {'name':'b','study_time':{'start':20,'end':21}},{'name':'b','study_time':{'start':11,'end':12}}]

for k,v in groupby(studentdetailsl, lambda x: x['name']):
    total_list.append(get_studetails(list(v)))
from pprint import pprint
pprint(total_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'a',
  'study_time': [{'end': 10, 'start': 9},
                 {'end': 12, 'start': 11},
                 {'end': 15, 'start': 13},
                 {'end': 19, 'start': 16},
                 {'end': 21, 'start': 20}]},
 {'name': 'b',
  'study_time': [{'end': 21, 'start': 20}, {'end': 12, 'start': 11}]}]
```